# HTML5 <canvas> scaling to different detected screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas

I'm making a simple app using the HTML5 <canvas> tag and compile the code into a native app using Cordova, but the issue is that canvas use coordinates that are not relative to the size of it, and we plan to have it across Apple and Google supported devices...which could mean at least more than 10 screen sizes/resolutions.

So I want to know how to work with a `<canvas>` (which will be in fullscreen) on different screen sizes.

Will using model-based coordinates help?

Thanks!

Comment: More importantly the screens are likely be of different aspect ratios, so using coordinates relative to the canvas size won't help you much (or will at least result in some odd-looking graphics).

Comment: And note that phone/tablet users can rotate their devices while looking at your page ...

Comment: yes Pointy, we would also like to make the app rotatable too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can only set one width and height in the canvas element itself.  If you want to change its size depending on portrait, landscape, etc., you could use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries).  I'm pretty sure that's going to make your canvas not look very high quality in certain situations, since you're essentially just blowing up or shrinking the size of a predefined element.

There might be a fancier way to redraw the canvas depending on screensize, etc., but I haven't tried it.

Comment: You can set width and height using [JavaScript/jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/pY8XK/). I think you mean that you should not change it with CSS.

Comment: yes @Zhihao i wouldnt want to change it with CSS as it degrades image quality. By javascript/jquery...is there any function out there that does it already, or must i code a library myself?

Comment: I don't know of any JavaScript or jQuery library that will help you change the dimensions of a canvas while also resizing the contents, if that's what you mean. I haven't worked with the canvas a great deal though so there may exist one out there that I'm not aware of. Unfortunately, resizing a canvas will also clear it in most cases. Perhaps it might be possible to save the canvas as an image, resize the image, and then draw it back onto the canvas after resizing?

Comment: Oh, certainly you wouldn't want to use CSS.  I'm just saying you *could*.  I just wasn't sure if you could resize the width and height w/ Javascript and have it work nicely, but I guess if you just make sure to redraw whatever was originally in the canvas to fit the new size, it'd be fine.